# Why am I receiving 500 - Internal Server Error with Oracle

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex, internal-server-error

I'm using Apex 4.2.4.00.08 / ORDS 3.0.7 / JRE 1.8.0.102 / Oracle XE 11g.  My server is Windows 10 with 16 Gb of memory.  I start ORDS using JRE 1.8.0.

I log into an existing Apex application and can get to most of the screens.  Recently I couldn't display a page that hasn't been modified in a year or so.  When I attempt to access the page The URL reads: http://localhost:9090/ords/wwv_flow.accept  and the error is: 500 - Internal Server Error.

The page is just an interactive report with a very simple query selecting fields from one table.  Based on some other posts, I turned on some Debug info by editing ....ords\ords\defaults.xml.  I added the line:

```
<entry key="debug.printDebugToScreen">true</entry>
```

and restarted the Java task for ORDS.  Now when I access the interactive report page I get the Debug info.  However, I still can't figure out what the problem is.  I looked up the error ORA-01044 based on the Debug, but most of the discussion is many years old.  I imported the application from another server to check if the application somehow got corrupt.  I got the same result.  Can you determine why I'm getting a 500 - Internal Server Error based on the following Debug?
DEBUG TRACE

```
[TE] url-mapping start: 2016-10-12T12:27:34.285Z duration: 0ms
[TE] POST /ords/wwv_flow.accept start: 2016-10-12T12:27:34.285Z duration: 21ms
```

STACK TRACE

```
InternalServerException [statusCode=500, reasons=[]]
    at oracle.dbtools.apex.ModApexContext.handleError(ModApexContext.java:273)
    at oracle.dbtools.apex.OWA.execute(OWA.java:206)
    at oracle.dbtools.apex.ModApex.handleRequest(ModApex.java:267)
    at oracle.dbtools.apex.ModApex.doPost(ModApex.java:174)
    at oracle.dbtools.apex.ModApex.service(ModApex.java:102)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.entrypoint.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:125)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.entrypoint.EntryPoint$FilteredServlet.service(EntryPoint.java:240)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:73)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.forwarding.QueryFilteringRewrite.doFilter(QueryFilteringRewrite.java:90)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.forwarding.ForwardingFilter.doFilter(ForwardingFilter.java:68)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.cors.CORSPreflightFilter.doFilter(CORSPreflightFilter.java:66)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.cookies.auth.CookieSessionCSRFFilter.doFilter(CookieSessionCSRFFilter.java:77)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.auth.AuthenticationFilter.authenticate(AuthenticationFilter.java:87)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.auth.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:62)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
    at oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.RequestMapperImpl.doFilter(RequestMapperImpl.java:125)
    at oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.URLMappingBase.doFilter(URLMappingBase.java:103)
    at oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.filter.URLMappingFilter.doFilter(URLMappingFilter.java:124)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.cors.CORSResponseFilter.doFilter(CORSResponseFilter.java:83)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpResponseFilter.doFilter(HttpResponseFilter.java:45)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.errors.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:94)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.auth.ForceAuthFilter.doFilter(ForceAuthFilter.java:44)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.Filters.filter(Filters.java:47)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.entrypoint.EntryPoint.service(EntryPoint.java:82)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.entrypoint.EntryPointServlet.service(EntryPointServlet.java:49)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at oracle.dbtools.rt.web.HttpEndpointBase.dispatchableServices(HttpEndpointBase.java:116)
    at oracle.dbtools.rt.web.HttpEndpointBase.service(HttpEndpointBase.java:81)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:751)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1045)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01044: size 7667478 of buffer bound to variable exceeds maximum gineWWV_FLOW_DATA_PK error

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:220)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:48)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:938)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1150)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4802)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4905)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:5631)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1385)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor12.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.proxy.StatementProxyFactory.invoke(StatementProxyFactory.java:353)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.proxy.PreparedStatementProxyFactory.invoke(PreparedStatementProxyFactory.java:178)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.proxy.CallableStatementProxyFactory.invoke(CallableStatementProxyFactory.java:136)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.execute(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.dbtools.apex.OWA.execute(OWA.java:169)
    ... 61 more
```